# Aggregating data based on different columns in hive

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have following columns

```
Loc_ID | Ctry  | Val2  | Val3  |
-------+-------+-------+-------+
 1     | 90    | 2.23  | 3.43  | 
 2     | 90    | 12.23 | Null  |
 2     | 90    | 9.05  | 13.43 |
 4     | 90    | 78.23 | 9.43  |
 5     | 91    | 2.23  | 3.43  | 
 6     | 91    | 12.23 | 2.92  |
 7     | 91    | Null  | 13.43 |
 7     | 91    | 78.23 | 9.43  |
```

where Ctry is country code.  How to find which Location ID has maximum of total Val2 in these two countries

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `limit`:

```
select loc_id, sum(val2) as sum_val2
from t
group by loc_id
order by sum_val2 desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your requirement to get the location ids with most total val2 in each of the countries. Please correct if I am wrong.

Solution is as below

```
WITH v_max_tot
AS
(SELECT Ctry, Loc_ID, SUM(Val2) AS Val2_Total ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ctry ORDER BY SUM(Val2) DESC) AS r_num
  FROM ramesh_tab
 GROUP BY Ctry, Loc_ID)
SELECT Ctry, Loc_ID
  FROM v_max_tot
 WHERE r_num =1 ;
```

Output is as below for the sample data provided in the question

[image]

Explatnaion

- v_max_tot - Gets the sum of val2 for each country, location and assigns a sequence number based on total value desc
- main select - filters the record with the highest total val2.

Hope this helps